# My Ajax GET isn't working .

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

This is my first encounter with Ajax and I'm also new to . . . everything!

Eventually I want to get values out of a database, but just to check I've got Ajax working, all I'm trying to do is get it to display a line of text.

Here is my code:

```
function loadSection(section)
{
if (section=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("entry").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("entry").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","getentry.php&q="+section,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

And here's the PHP:

```
<?php

$section = $GET[$section]; //not currently doing anything, will be needed when     
actually searching database

echo "fingers crossed";


?>
```

As far as I can tell the only thing I'm doing different to the example on the W3Schools site it putting the Ajax in a separate .js file, but it also doesn't work when I include it in the main page.

Any help much appreciated!

**Edit to add:** thanks guys! jraede correctly figured out the function was never getting called, and the jquery tip-off is also appreciated :-)

Comment: Are you supporting IE6, IE5 for any particular reason? Have you got a server set up? Any errors in the console?

Comment: is not getentry.php&q=, try with getentry.php?q=

Comment: jquery would make this easier to learn

Comment: (jQuery would not make it easier at all)

Comment: well 5 to 1 disagree @minitech :-)

Comment: @minitech I'm making a blog site for a friend, and figure making it as widely usable as possible is a good idea. Yup I have a server set up. The PHP runs fine when I just do 'include getentry.php'

Answer (score 0):

you should writ like this-

```
$section = $GET['q'];
```

Answer (score 0):

is not
 `getentry.php&q=`,

try with

`getentry.php?q=`

And in $_GET should be `$_GET['q']`

If you are using chrome, open console and see if there is any errors.

Comment: Made both those changes and still no luck. I am using chrome, and in the console when I hit the button, nothing at all happens!

Comment: Open up the network tab to see the request going out, and then you can see what the response is.

Comment: ok weird . . . nothing at all is happening when I hit that button

Comment: You are likely never calling your loadSection function. See my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com)

You could simple use [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) to fetch the required information.

Example of `$.get()`

```
    $.get( "getentry.php?q=" + section, function( data ) {
       // log response in console.
       console.log(data);
    });
```

Comment: it doesn't answer your question.  but it is an easier way to accomplish what you're going for

Comment: @minitech yes I was just offering a different approach.

Comment: thank you - this does look simpler, although just changing to this wasn't enough to fix it.

Comment: @Feathers what errors are showing up? (also just double checking that you included the jquery library - `http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js`)

Comment: heya yup I included the library - no errors were being thrown, looks like it was just never getting called. Switching from onchange to onclick appears to have fixed it

Comment: @Feathers - yeah that would probably be best. Altough you could use jquery `.on()` to pick up the click then run the get request :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that could be going wrong here, so it would help to have more information. However, going from what you have provided, I can identify the following areas that you should check:

**1) Make sure that your syntax is correct in both javascript and PHP.**

Your javascript has a few errors that people have already pointed out, namely that `"getentry.php&q="` should be `"getentry.php?q="`.

In your PHP, you are trying to retrieve `$GET[$section]`, which has two errors. First, to retrieve variables from the query string, you need to use `$_GET`, not `$GET`. Second, assuming `$section` isn't yet defined or, at least that there is no matching variable in the query string, this code would return a blank value. As many have already pointed out, this should be `$_GET['q']`.

**2) Make sure your script is doing what you think it's doing.**

Where are you calling your `loadSection()` function? Are you calling it at all? Try using `alert` or `console.log` to spit out the value of `section` within that function - maybe it's not being set?

**3) Make sure the request is going out, and check if you are getting a response**

With Chrome you can open up the developer tools, click on the network tab, and watch AJAX requests go out and view their response. Open up the network tab, refresh the page, do whatever you need to do to call your `loadSection()` function, and then click on the "preview" or "response" tab to see what your server has responded. It could be that the actual AJAX request is working fine and it's just not doing anything with the response.

**4) Make sure that your response is acted upon**

I see that you have code to set the innerHTML of #entry with whatever the response text is. Make sure there is an element with `id="entry"` somewhere on the page, and that it is on the page at the time that this code is run. Also, try using `console.log` on the `xmlhttp` object in your `onreadystatechange` function to see what it is doing. It could be that the status code is never set to 200 or the `readyState` is never set to 4.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply :-) I think you were right when you said it was never getting called - changing to the jquery approach described in another answer AND changing the button to onclick seems to be solving it :-)

Comment: Going back to how you had it initially, you can define all the functions you want, but you need to *call* them somehow in order for them to be executed. Putting the function in a button's `onclick` event would do that, or you could call it directly by just running `loadSection('name_of_section');` after you define the function.